# Sum of a set of numbers squared is larger than $N$ times the mean squared

Tags: statistics

I require the proof for the following

$$\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i^2 \ge N \mu ^2 $$

where $x_i \in \mathbb R$ and

$$\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N x_i$$

I can visually see how this is true (I imagine rectangles and squares), and would like to know if there's a common name for the result. If not, what's an easy way to show a proof for this? Thanks!

Comment: in what context do you require this proof? what have you tried? how about doing this for small $N$ to build intuition? e.g. for $N=1$, does this always hold? what about for $N=2$?

Comment: I need it to prove a result I have (that uses this). I know this result is true, I just want some easy way for me to explain how I am able to use it. A name works best, but if there's none, a simple proof that's easy to follow would be nice. I don't want to take time/space explaining something that's not as important/relevant to my study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}{N} \ge \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}\right)^2$$
may be called Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and can be proved by

- [Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) with $u_i = x_i, v_i = 1$
- [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) with $f(x) = x^2$
- [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) with $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = 1, (p,q) = (2;2)$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the random variable $X$ takes $x_i,~i=1,2,...,N$ with uniform probabilities, which is:

$$P(X=x_i)=\frac{1}N,~~~~~~~~i=1,2,...,N$$

So we have $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)\ge0$, which gives:

$$E(X^2)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N x_i^2 \ge E^2(X)= \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N x_i\right)^2=\mu^2 $$

Done.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: Thank you, glad you like it!